# How can I horizontally align text. One word at center and second word at right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

How can I horizontally align text. One word at center and second word at right?

```
[              [One word at center]      [Second right]]
```

Comment: thanks for answers. I just want to add the way with bootstrap use. `<div class="text-center">
 <span>center</span>
 <span class="float-right">right</span>
</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<p style="text-align:center;">
    <span>Center</span>
    <span style="float:right;">Right</span>
    <div class="clearix"></div>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to give parent class of both texts to *'text-align: center'* and give second text *'float: right'* style. Here is an example how to do that.

HTML

```
<div>
 <span>[One word at center]</span>
 <span class="right">[second right]</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div{
 text-align: center;
}
.right{
 float:right;
}
```

[Live example on fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcean2p4/)